# Server to Server Postback tracking issue for redirect URL

Tags: php, tracking, affiliate

How can we put a redirect for server to server post back tracking?

For ex: we have a URL which user clicks :

http://tracking1.pubsarena.com/aff_c?offer_id=626&aff_id=2

and in backend it runs a script of third party to score fraud and then send it to the below URL:

http://vtgtrk.com/?a=1867&c=27&s1={affiliate_id}&s2={transaction_id}

We have created a code, but it creates a loop between tracking1 and fraud detection API and stays on tracking1 instead of going to vtgtrk. It works fine if we use an iframe on vtgtrk page.

But we want to use server to server postback to record conversion.

tracking1 is redirect URL to score fraud before sending it to vtgtrk.

Please help. How we can solve this issue?

Comment: Show the code that you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are using hasoffers. you should add `{affiliate_id}` & `{transaction_id}` inside the default offer url of your advertiser's offer. something like (ex :cake platform) : `s1={affiliate_id}&s2={transaction_id}`.

in the postback url make something like : the `adv_sub=#s1#&transaction_id=#s2#`

conclusion : if you send 2 variables you need to get them back with `subid1` and `subid2` tokens of your advertisers and with the same classement. and the same thing if a network get offers from you, he needs to add his parameters to your `aff_subs` & use this tokens in his `s2s` postback `{aff_sub}` & `{affsub2}`

i hope this can help you.

Regards,